# Roslyn analyzer does not respect .editorconfig

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, rider, editorconfig

Does anybody know why Roslyn analyzer does not respect indent_style from .editorconfig?

I'm using Rider on mac and we decided to configure code rules in our solution.

Here's our setup from .editorconfig:

```
# Remove the line below if you want to inherit .editorconfig settings from higher directories
root = true

# C# files
[*.cs]
#### Core EditorConfig Options ####

# Indentation and spacing
indent_size = tab
indent_style = tab
tab_width = 4

# New line preferences
end_of_line = crlf
insert_final_newline = false
```

And it looks like Rider is reading this config and knows that it should use tabs on each new line, but Roslyn complains that formatting should be fixed.

[image]

Can somebody help me with this? Is there any way to configure indent style for Roslyn analyzer?

Comment: Does this reproduce outside of Rider? It's hard to tell based on your description which side the bug might be on, and it could be on both sides.

Comment: This problem could be either from Rider or Roslyn Analyzer.  I don't see such issue on windows/Visual studio. And please check if the suggestion is really wrong? You claim the indent to be tab, are you using spaces thus trigger the fixer?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski I've checked in Visual Studio on Windows and it works as expected. The problem seems to be in Rider or macOS

Comment: @joe Yup, as you can see from my .editorconfig code, I've set indent_style = tab, but in editor screenshot analyzer is complaining to change tab indentations to spaces. I didn't find any solution for this